# Need to search for a node. if not present need to enter an empty node using xslt

Tags: xslt

The below is the Response for a Web Service.

```
   <Envelope>
      <Body>
        <searchItemResponse>
          <status>
            <statusCode>Success</statusCode>
          </status>
          <itemList>
            <itemWithWarehouses>
              <item>
                <originOfData>SME</originOfData>
                <itemNumbers>
                   <shortNumber>115632</shortNumber>
                   <tssArticleNumber>PT0401450-T46N</tssArticleNumber>
                   <relatedItems>
                      <alternateItemsNumber>ORAR00428-N7083</alternateItemsNumber> 
                   </relatedItems>
              </item>
              <warehouseItems>
                   .....................
              </warehouseItems>
              <warehouseItems>
                   .....................
              </warehouseItems>
            </itemWithWarehouses>
          </itemList>
        </searchItemResponse>
      </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

In some cases the below node is missing.

```
<relatedItems>
  <alternateItemsNumber>ORAR00428-N7083</alternateItemsNumber> 
</relatedItems>
```

I need to make sure if the node is not there, i need to insert the node like shown below

```
<relatedItems>
  <alternateItemsNumber/>
</relatedItems>
```

I need an XSLT for this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Is that **all** the XSLT stylesheet needs to do?

Comment: I'd be inclined to question why you need to- it makes no sense to add an element for data that isn't there. Surely whatever's handling the xml should be adapted to gracefully handle the absence of the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a template looking for any `itemNumbers` not having a `relatedItems` element and then add the empty elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="" version="2.0" xpath-default-namespace="" exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="itemNumbers[not(relatedItems)]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
            <xsl:element name="relatedItems">
                <xsl:element name="alternateItemsNumber"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>    

</xsl:stylesheet>
```